# Export data to excel & color entire row based on value in the cell using XLSX in angular

Tags: angular, xlsx

My data :

```
[{'name':'ABC','Value':'100'},
{'name':'XYZ','Value':'25'},
{'name':'QWE','Value':'75'}]
```

while exporting to excel, if Value column is <50 row should be yellow else green.

output should look like this..

[image]

Can anyone help me to achieve it...

Thanks..!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented your requirements using exceljs and file-saver js

Please check the working example. If you have any pop up blocker in your browser please off it while checking this example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9p6cch?file=src/app/app.component.ts

[image]